# Angular Select with an option value of space

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a `<select>` with an `ng-model`, and one of the options is a space. When the initial value is something else, angular selects the right option, but when the initial value is a space, angular adds the empty option.

I can reproduce it with html like:

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-trim="false">
  <option value=" ">Default</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="b">
  <option value="x">Default</option>
</select>
```

and a controller like:

```
$scope.a = " ";
$scope.b = "x";
```

The first select will have a blank option and the second will show "Default". Adding `ng-trim` doesn't seem to help, and I'm getting the values from a database so I can't easily change them.

I can reproduce the issue with Angular 1.4.8, 1.4.9 (which I'm using) and 1.5.8, all from https://code.angularjs.org/.

I have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d1cj3kzb/4/.

How can I get the `<select>` to show the correct option when `ng-model` is initialized to a space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring a variable in your code that has the value of your default, in this case space, like:

$scope.spaceChar = " ";

and then in your select:

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-trim="false">
    <option value="{{spaceChar}}">Default</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No luck, still goes to the blank option.

Comment: Are you sure? I used your fiddle and it seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/d1cj3kzb/5/

Comment: You're right, this works! I made a typo when trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Apply ng-trim to your option:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="a" >
      <option value=" " ng-trim="true">Default</option>
    </select>

    <select ng-model="b">
      <option value="x">Default</option>
    </select>
```

trim your variable before binding.

```
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("MyCtrl",
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.a = (" ").trim();
        $scope.b = "x";
    }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that changes the value of `a`, which I want to send back to the server as `" "`. I might do this if I can't find a way around it.

Comment: `(" ").trim();` would be `""`, so how can it analyse that its space?

Comment: @Andrew : I think getting data from data base and before binding it to options you will have to process your data in a way so that it also does not have duplicates. i.e  <option value=" " ng-trim="true">Default</option>
      <option value=" " ng-trim="true">Default2</option>